# Applying navbar colour changes to dropdown menu

Tags: html, css, navbar

I'm trying to apply colour changes to the text in my navbar for the links that:have been visited, are currently active, and are being hovered over. It's working fine for all my regular hyperlink elements, however since I've already occupied the 'class' descriptor for my dropdown menu button (button class="dropbtn"), I can't figure out how I can make it change colour when the user is on a page from the dropdown menu, or how to make it change colour once visited, since you never really 'visit' the button, only the links within it.

```css
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}

.dropbtn:hover {
  color: #874c16;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.dropbtn:visited {
  color: #8b4e14;
}

.dropbtn.active {
  color: #ffe7d1;
}

.navbar a:hover {
  color: #874c16;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.navbar a:visited {
  color: #8b4e14;
}

.navbar a.active {
  color: #ffe7d1;
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar">
  <a href="index.html">Home</a>
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropbtn">Cuisine 
       <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
     </button>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="indian.xml">Indian</a>
      <a href="italian.xml">Italian</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <a href="http://www.blogtyrant.com/best-about-us-pages/">About us</a>
  <a href="http://www.blogtyrant.com/best-contact-us-pages/">Contact</a>
  <a href="https://media.termsfeed.com/pdf/terms-and-conditions-template.pdf">Terms and Conditions</a>
  <a href="https://www.visser.com.au/blog/generic-privacy-policy-for-australian-websites/">Privacy Policy</a>
  <a href="datacollect.html">Customer Feedback</a>

</div>
```

Despite the solution probably being simply, I've been at this for a long time and will HIGHLY appreciate any input. Thanks guys (:

Edit: changing the button class to an anchor class also doesn't work because the top "cuisine" anchor is never actually clicked, only the anchor elements within it.

Edit 2: I wasn't clear in my question, I want "cuisine" to change colour when the user is one the page that is linked from any of the anchors within it. So when they click on "Indian" or "Italian", I want cuisine to be a different colour to if they were on say the home page. I also want "cuisine" to change its default colour if it has been visited in the past.

Answer (score 1):

pseudo-classes `:visited` `:active` doesn't appy to `button` elements but only to `a` elements.
So it is better if you rewrite your button code and transform it into an anchor `a` element.

```js
$('.dropdown a').click(function () {
  $('.dropdown').css('background', 'red');
});
```

```css
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {


display: block;

}
.dropbtn {
  display:block;
  height: 30px;
  line-height:30px;
  width: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  background:#ccc;
  border-radius:5px;
  border: 1px solid #bbb;
  text-decoration: none
}
.dropbtn:hover{
    color:#874c16;
    font-size:20px;

}

.dropbtn:visited{
    color:#8b4e14;
}


.dropbtn.active{
    color:#ffe7d1;
}


.navbar a:hover{
    color:#874c16;
    font-size:20px;

}
.navbar a:visited{
    color:#8b4e14;
}


.navbar a.active{
    color:#ffe7d1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="navbar">
            <a href="index.html"  >Home</a>
            <div class="dropdown">
                <a class="dropbtn" href="#">Cuisine 
                  <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
                </a>
                <div class="dropdown-content">
                  <a href="indian.xml">Indian</a>
                  <a href="italian.xml">Italian</a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <a href="http://www.blogtyrant.com/best-about-us-pages/">About us</a>
            <a href="http://www.blogtyrant.com/best-contact-us-pages/">Contact</a>
            <a href="https://media.termsfeed.com/pdf/terms-and-conditions-template.pdf">Terms and Conditions</a>
            <a href="https://www.visser.com.au/blog/generic-privacy-policy-for-australian-websites/">Privacy Policy</a>
            <a href="datacollect.html">Customer Feedback</a>

        </div>
```

Comment: I tried that but it still doesn't work because even if it is an anchor element it is never actually clicked because it's the anchor elements within the drop down that are selected, so the compiler never knows that  "cuisine"  is entered. @Daniele Fois

Comment: I didn't undestand. Maybe you need to specify better what you want to achieve. Do you want to light up the parent element in the dropdown menu?

Comment: I want "cuisine" to change colour when the user is on a page that is linked from any of the anchors within it. So when they click on "Indian" or "Italian", I want cuisine to be a different colour to if they were on say the home page. I also want "cuisine" to change its default colour if it has been visited in the past. Sorry for not being clear.

Comment: As far as I know I'm not using one? The pages are XML pages, styled with XSLT and all of the content is local, accessed by relative links like /images.

Comment: you need to set the parent element class to something you can select via css... you can use js/jquery to do it...

Comment: I edited my snippet and introduced a little jquery script to do it

Comment: I'm new to all of this. If i want to use js would i be able to make it like this?

'<script type="text/javascript">' 
var button = document.feedbackform.dropbtn
</script>

Comment: I did but I wanted to do it with js because I understand js at little bit. And how would the function work? doesn't css prioritize things that are lower on the page, so even if I called the function when it's clicked and made the function change the css, wouldn't it change right back when the next line of css is read?

Comment: I have been using google all along. Strange of you to put time into helping me but then give up just before it becomes useful. Thanks anyway I guess, back to square one.